Classification of centralizers of elements of finite simple groups of Lie type
I am currently studying the twisted Ree finite simple groups given by $^2G_2(3^{2n+1})$ and I was wondering if there is a reference for the classification of centralizers of elements in this family of finite simple groups.
Thank you for any help.

There are two families of finite simple groups that fit that description, ${}^2G_2(3^{2n+1})$ and ${}^2F_4(2^{2n+1})$.

Thank you for pointing that out. I will edit the question to specify the class of finite simple groups I mean.

Their maximal subgroups are determined in a paper of Kleidman in J. Algebra 117 (1988), 30–71. It should not be too hard to determine the centralizers of elements from this, since every such centralizer is contained in a maxial subgroup.

The paper referenced by @DerekHolt: Kleidman - The maximal subgroups of the Chevalley groups $G_2(q)$ with $q$ odd, the Ree groups ${{}^2G_2}(q)$, and their automorphism groups.

Thank you for the reference. I will look through it and when I have the classification of the centralizers, I will post it as a response to my own question.
